# affiliations and corresponding author comment as footnotes on latex article

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tex, footnotes

I am trying to use the LaTeX article document class to create a simple paper with the authors listed on the title page with their (potentially multiple repeating) affiliations as numeric footnotes and other author comments as symbolic footnotes. For example, I want something like

[image]

However, I haven't been able to make this happen despite trying multiple different solutions. Is there a simple way to do this?

I have tried using the `bigfoot` package to create multiple different types of footnotes combined with `footmisc` with the `multiple` option to get multiple footnote markers with commas between them, but I end up with superposed markers and no footnotes. My minimal latex document is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\title{My title}

\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{AAffil}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote{ANote}[fnsymbol]

\author{
        David Kaplan\footnoteAAffil{A University}\footnoteAAffil{Another University}\footnoteANote{Corresponding author}\footnoteANote{Equal contributors}
        \and
        Prince Charming\FootnotemarkAAffil{2}\FootnotemarkANote{2}
}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

And the output I get is:

[image]

Comment: While you wait for an answer, maybe you can read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work to pass the time

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are sending this to me?

Comment: did you get any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to switch to the `amsart` class and then using the `amsaddr` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{My title}

\author{David Kaplan $^{1,2,\ast,\dagger}$}
\address{$^1$A University}
\address{$^2$Another University}
\address{$^{\ast}$Corresponding author}
\address{$^{\dagger}$Equal contributors}
\author{Prince Charming $^{1,\dagger}$}

\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With help from others, I posted a solution to this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604502/246058). For completeness, I am copying the solution below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}  % <---- No titlepage

\title{My title}

%\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}   % <---- I decided not to use fnpct, but rather put in the commas by hand
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{AAffil}[arabic]
\DeclareNewFootnote{ANote}[fnsymbol]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\maketitle{\def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

% Hook into the \thanks command for the article class to print the footnotes
\makeatletter
\def\thanksAAffil#1{% <--- These %'s are necessary for spacing
  \footnotemarkAAffil\protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks%
        \protect\footnotetextAAffil[\the \c@footnoteAAffil]{#1}}%
}
\def\thanksANote#1{%
  \footnotemarkANote%
  \protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks%
        \protect\footnotetextANote[\the \c@footnoteANote]{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\author{% <---- Not sure if these %'s are necessary, but can't hurt
  David Kaplan%
  \thanksAAffil{A University}$^{,}$\thanksAAffil{Another University}$^{,}$%
  \thanksANote{Corresponding author}$^{,}$\thanksANote{Equal contributors}%
  , %
  Prince Charming%
  \footnotemarkAAffil[2]$^{,}$\thanksAAffil{Still another university}$^{,}$\footnotemarkANote[2]$^{,}$%
  \thanksANote{Another note}%
  , %
  Mohamed Ali%
  \thanksAAffil{I am the greatest U.}%
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

More Text

\end{document}
```